# Power Shell issue with pydoc: "--More--" in last line and then can't type

Tags: python, shell, pydoc

I started learning Python recently. I'm using Zed Shaw's "Learning Python The Hard Way" and running my exercises mostly in Power Shell. OS is Windows 7 and I have Python 2.7.

Chapter 12 mentions pydoc. So here's the problem I'm running into with pydoc. Normally, I type in python -m pydoc whatever, it gives me the definition, and then returns to C:\Users\User. But occasionally, instead of that, it gives me "--More--" in the last line and then I can't type anything. Messages appear on the screen if I press certain keys (I will post them if required) but I can't actually type. I have to restart power shell to use it again. Anyone know anything about it?

Comment: Does this also happen on the normal `cmd` shell?

Comment: Yes, it does. In both shells it happens occasionally, not always.

Answer (score 1):

"--More--" means there is more stuff to show

Press **Enter** to show a line more, u can keep doing that

Press **q** to quit pydocs mode

Comment: Press **s** and a prompt `lines: ` appears, but I'm not sure how this works